# Need Assistance with a JavaScript Function for the "Paper, Rock, Sissors Challenge."

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, console.log

I am testing my playRound() function and not receiving the desired results with a console.log output.  The output is always the initial return of the if statement.

I have initialized the global variable of playerChoice to equal a string, i.e. “rock”.

I have verified that the output of the getComputerChoice() functions generates a random selection from the array, .i.e. paper, rock or scissors, with console.log(getComputerChoice()).

However, when I call the playRound() function I only receive the initial return on the if statement of “It’s a tie”.

```js
const playerSelection = "rock"
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
console.log(playRound());

function getComputerChoice() {
    const choice = ["paper", "rock", "sissors"];
    return choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return "It is a tie!";
    }   else {
        return "Please try again!";
    }
}
```

Why does the code seem to short circuit at the initial return of the if statement and never proceed to outputting “Try Again?”

[console.log(getComputerChoice())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Vq3.png)
[console.log(playRound())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7KfQ.png)

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question about your code, not your project.

Comment: Add the code that actually calls your `playRound()` function. Use [Edit].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
playRound()
```

doesn't pass any values to the function.  So within the function `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` are always `undefined`.  Within that function you are declaring those two local variables with the same name as two global variables.  The local variables *shadow* those global variables, so you can only use the local ones.

If you meant to use the global variables, don't re-declare local variables of the same name:

```js
const playerSelection = "rock"
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
console.log(playRound());

function getComputerChoice() {
    const choice = ["paper", "rock", "sissors"];
    return choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function playRound() {
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return "It is a tie!";
    }   else {
        return "Please try again!";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you do want to use local variables in that function, pass your values to it (and I recommend giving them different names to avoid confusion):

```js
const playerSelection = "rock"
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));

function getComputerChoice() {
    const choice = ["paper", "rock", "sissors"];
    return choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function playRound(pl, cmp) {
    if (pl === cmp) {
        return "It is a tie!";
    }   else {
        return "Please try again!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was able to get the desired results after reviewing and adjust my code block accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the playerSelection and computerSelection parameters in playRound() function as they are acting as local variables and not global variables. hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was able to get the desired results after reviewing and adjust my code block accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an introduction to how to get things working. lots of room for improvement though ;)

```js
function getComputerChoice() {
  const choice = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"];
  let result = choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  console.log('computer plays ' + result);
  return result;
};

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    console.log("It is a tie!");
    return;
  };
  if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
    console.log('Computer wins');
    return;
  }
  if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
    console.log('Computer wins');
    return;
  };
  if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
    console.log('Computer wins');
    return;
  }
  console.log('You Win!');
}
document.getElementById('playRock').addEventListener('click', (e) => this.playRound('rock', getComputerChoice()));

document.getElementById('playPaper').addEventListener('click', (e) => this.playRound('paper', getComputerChoice()));

document.getElementById('playScissors').addEventListener('click', (e) => this.playRound('scissors', getComputerChoice()));
```

```html
<button id="playRock">Shoot Rock</button>
<button id="playPaper">Shoot Paper</button>
<button id="playScissors">Shoot Scissors</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was able to adjust my initial code and expand it with this post.